# Determine whether a set contains a value other than that in a different set

Tags: python, python-3.x, set

I am looking to find if a set contains any value other than that contained in another set.

At the moment i have the code:

```
 set_entered = set(["ok_word_1", "ok_word_2", "not_ok_word"])
 set_allowable = set(["ok_word_1", "ok_word_2","ok_word_3", "ok_word_4"])

 set_entered_temp = set(set_entered)
 for item in set_allowable :
    set_1_temp.discard(item)
 if len(set_entered_temp ) > 0:
     print ("additional terms")
 else:
    print ("no additional terms")
```

Is there a simpler way of doing this? It is obviously trivially easy to see if a set contains an element [e.g. union of sets], but couldn't see an obvious way of seeing whether a set contained an element other than that in a set.

Update

Just to clarify, I am only looking to see if there is a term in the `entered set` which does not appear in the `allowable` set. [i.e am not looking to see if there is a difference between the two sets, rather just whether there are values in the entered set which are not in the other one].

Comment: That's what `set.difference()` is for

Comment: After your update: that is still what `set.difference` is for: `{1,2}.difference({2,3}) -> {1}` it doesn't worry about things that are contained in the second set but not the first.

Comment: You might be thinking of [`set.symmetric_difference`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set.symmetric_difference): `{1,2}.symmetric_difference({2,3}) -> {1,3}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can [substract](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set.difference) the two sets:

```
if set_1 - set_2:
    print("Additional terms")
```

Every element in `set_2` will be removed from `set_1`. If the resulted set is not empty, this means there was at least one value in `set_1` not contained into `set_2`.

Note that an empty set is interpreted as `False`, this is why this `if` condition works.

Answer (score 3):

Simply calculate difference of two [sets](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=set#set).

> `difference(other, ...)`
>
> `set - other - ...`
>
> Return a new set with
>   elements in the set that are not in the others.

```
x = bool(set_1 - set_2)  # if boolean is needed

if set_1 - set_2:  # simple check in boolean context
    pass
```

Answer (score 2):

```
set_diff = set_1.difference(set_2)
if set_diff:
    print ("additional terms")
else:
    print ("no additional terms")
```